# where are the windows users names stored in xp...?

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I am writing an application that searches for a particular file in the C:\Documents and Settings\user accounts\Application Data folder. Now i am trying to make this application generic. I can make this application search in a particular users application data folder. But what i am tryin to do is take the user name from a certain file or place where windows xp stores it. Then make it search for that user. Is there a particular way to do it.

Need ideas and suggestions.

Comment: .Net provides all kinds of methods for doing this kind of thing.  You need to be more specific about what you want.  You say you're being generic, but then you make it complicated.  Why don't you just work with the currently logged in user?

Comment: but i want to run it as an administrator. When as as admin i want to check the application data folder of each user for a certain file.

Comment: Then iterate each folder under Documents and Settings for its Application Data folder.  Or enumerate them all from the registry.

Comment: can u explain. what do u mean by enumenrate them all from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

User Names are Stored in Windows Registry or Use Can get FolderNames as `C:\Documents and Settings` contains Every Folder with a UserName

Comment: It's true that the registry stores user informataion, but that is just the wrong way to go about this.  And the folder names under Documents and Settings do not necessarily match the profile names.

Comment: where actually in the Windows Registry are the user names stored. Can u show me a direction

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Microsoft has not provided an API method of doing this directly.  Perhaps it was an oversight.  That being said, any solution you find is going to be some kind of workaround and is going to present some kind of limitations.

Using the registry to get this information is not officially supported by Microsoft and thus, may not work going forward.

Iterating through user profile folders is unreliable because the folder is not always named after its user and because you can change its location.

And so on.

All of that being said, I use a combination of WMI and the registry to accomplish this.  Here's what it looks like in VBScript, you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
  ' Create some arrays to hold the data.

arrUsers = Array()
arrSIDs = Array()
arrAppDataFolders = Array()

 ' Get a list of all the non-system users with their SID
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2"
Set colUsers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where Status = 'OK'")

i = 0
For Each objUser in colUsers
    ReDim Preserve arrUsers(i)
    ReDim Preserve arrSIDs(i)
    arrUsers(i) = objUser.Name
    arrSIDs(i) = objUser.SID
    i = i + 1
Next

Set colUsers = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing

  ' Now go to the registry and get the Document folder location using the SID
Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

ReDim arrAppDataFolders(UBound(arrSIDs))
For i = 0 to UBound(arrSIDs)
    strKeyPath = arrSIDs(i) & "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
    strValueName = "AppData"      ' or "Local AppData"
    intReturn = objRegistry.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_USERS, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
    If (intReturn = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then
        arrAppDataFolders(i) = strValue
    Else
        arrAppDataFolders(i) = vbNull
    End If
Next

Set objRegistry = Nothing
```

Answer (score -2):

```
net user
```

from a command prompt will return a list of all users... probably more than what you're asking for. Your best bet is to do what you had already planned on doing with your Documents and Settings.